# Angular kendo grid editing dynamic fields

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-dropdown

In kendo grid editing mode I have  dropdownlist.

The data of the dropdownlist is changes every time.
I try to load the data of the dropdownlist with [data]="dataItem[column.field_name]"

But it's incorrect.

How can I give each time different data object name.

The name of the object is coming from db.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Construct your data in TypeScript before giving it to your template.

```js
data = []

function constructData(serverData, column) {
    this.data = serverData.map((dataItem) => dataItem[column.field_name]);
}
```

and then pass the `data` in your template `[data]="data"`

Comment: The problem is that it can be couple of dropdownlist. I get the fields type of the editing grid from the db.    I recieved object with row structure (what fields type I have in the editing grid, and for the dropdownlist I get the objects with unique names)